# How to build & run xcodeproj on simulator from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

All I want to do is be able to do the same thing as `Cmd` + `R`that I'm able to do in Xcode, except from the Terminal. But so far look at multiple stack overflow posts and articles have left me lost.

So far I've been able to run the simulator from the command line:

```
open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <UDID for iPhone 7>
```

But I've been unable to install and launch the application using these commands

```
xcrun simctl install booted <PATH-TO-APPLICATION-BUNDLE>
xcrun simctl launch booted <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE>
```

I don't know how to find the `<PATH-TO-APPLICATION-BUNDLE>`. I'm assuming it's not as easy as just putting the path to the `.xcodeproj`...

If anyone could write the steps & specific commands I need to (1) build `.xcodeproj` from command line and (2) run the app on the simulator from the command line that would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I know there are tools like [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) that probably make this whole process easier, but I'd like to do it raw (i.e. using Xcode command line tools)

Comment: After build.. do you know where is you .app file?

Answer (score 4):

(1) To build you project I suggest you check this link
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

(2) This is an example on how I launched an app on simulator

**List devices**

```
xcrun simctl list
```

**Boot device**

(example)

```
xcrun simctl boot "iPhone 5"
```

or 
(example)

```
xcrun simctl boot E9469085-68B9-450A-A716-87F013C9AF56
```

**Install .app** (gotta find your Library folder.. could be hidden)

format: xcrun simctl install < device > < .app path >
(example)

```
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 5" "MyUserPath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomTransitions-edghiwbzifosladnxssmsfwzykxg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomTransitions.app"
```

**Shutdown device**

```
xcrun simctl boot "iPhone 5"
```

**Open simulator** (this is my path.. yours can be different)

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

**Launch the app**

format: xcrun simctl launch booted < bundle id >

```
xcrun simctl launch booted "com.example.apple-samplecode.CustomTransitions"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command to launch and run the app

```
$ ios-sim launch --devicetypeid "iPhone-7" ".app path"
```